# How to remove the extra vertical lines in a table

Tags: tables

There are two vertical lines on top of my table that are not supposed to be there. It looks something like this:

|                               |

```
   Table 1: Title
```

This is the beginning of my code:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{table}[h!]

        \centering

            \begin{tabular}{|p{.5in}|C{1.2in}|C{1.4in}|C{1.2in}|} \\

            \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Table 7: Efficiency Analysis}} \\

            \hline \hline
```

How do I remove those two vertical lines?

Comment: Please always make a *complete*, compilable example, not just snippets. And try removing the ```\\``` after `\begin{tabular}{..}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That `\\\` is most likely the cause of the vertical lines....

Comment: @Reg You should write `\begin{tabular}{p{.5in}|C{1.2in}|C{1.4in}|C{1.2in}}` for better result. The outside lines are unnecessary.  But please complete the MWE.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution to getting rid of the unwanted pair of vertical bars is to remove the directive `\\` that occurs immediately after `\begin{tabular}{...}`.

A better -- certainly more elegant -- solution comes from recognizing that you currently don't seem to be using LaTeX's `\caption` command to generate captions. Instead of typing

```
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Table 7: Efficiency Analysis}} \\
```

you really ought to just write

```
\caption{Efficiency Analysis}
```

Let LaTeX take care of the chores of figuring out the table's number, etc. If you need to have the caption typeset in bold, just load the `caption` package with the option `text=bf`. Loading the `caption` package will also result in the insertion of a bit of vertical whitespace between the caption and the `tabular` material, creating visual separation of the two elements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set margins to suit your needs
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
Original version, with unwanted pair of vertical bars

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{.5in}|C{1.2in}|C{1.4in}|C{1.2in}|} \\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Table 7: Efficiency Analysis}} \\
\hline \hline
a & b & c & d
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\bigskip
Simple modification: Remove the first \verb+\\+ directive
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{.5in}|C{1.2in}|C{1.4in}|C{1.2in}|} 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Table 7: Efficiency Analysis}} \\
\hline \hline
a & b & c & d
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\bigskip
Better modification: Use the \verb+\caption+ command (\emph{and}  still remove the first \verb+\\+ directive)
\setcounter{table}{6} % just for this example
\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{Efficiency Analysis}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{.5in}|C{1.2in}|C{1.4in}|C{1.2in}|} 
\hline \hline
a & b & c & d
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```